# Difference between deterrent and hindrance?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I have this sentence:

> In India analysts attributed high cost of Apple's devices to be a
>   major **deterrent** to sales of iPhone that completes with android
>   based smartphones.

My question is why can't I use *[hindrance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hindrance)* in the above sentence in place of *deterrent* because *hindrance* also means a factor causing trouble in achieving a positive result or tending to produce a negative result as indicated below:

> Hindrance: a thing that provides resistance, delay, or obstruction to something
>   or someone: '*a hindrance to the development process*'

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: Welcome to ELU. As this is a site dealing with *English*, would you mind editing your question to punctuate your sentences and capitalise your words appropriately? Regarding multiple questions, this site's convention is to ask a separate question separately. (I see that Rathony has done both for you in the time it took me to write this comment. :) )

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. This site is [a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and please check typos when you post a question. Also, one question per post is the guideline of Stack Exchange and I deleted your second question. If you need to ask it, please post another question, but you have to show your own research efforts.

Comment: @Lawrence I am that kind. :-)

Comment: ... @Rathony :)

Comment: Hindrance and deterrent are both somewhat 'off' in this context. You might want to try something like *detraction from sales* instead. If used *figuratively*, both *hindrance* and *deterrent* can work. To *hinder* a sale is to tend to prevent the sale from completing. To *deter* it is to tend to prevent the sales process (for that customer) from even starting.

Comment: ... Perhaps not a matter of *figurative* language. *Hinder* and *detract* apply more to a sales *process* than the *number* of sales (or some other collective quantity relevant to sales, such as *revenue*).

Comment: @Lawrence Agree that they are off in the sentence as written, but possibly if the sentence were recast to something like *In India analysts attributed the level of iPhone sales, in competition with Android based smartphones, to the deterrent/hindering effect of high cost of Apple’s devices* they work better?

Comment: @Spagirl Yes, that would be better. In your revised version, *deter/hinder* is implicitly applied to the sales processes rather than to the aggregates.

Comment: What @Lawrence said. But note that ***deter*** more strongly implies someone *deliberately* trying to stop something (which may or may not have already started), whereas ***hinder*** tends to apply to circumstances (often no more "volitional" than the forces of nature or happenstance) which make it difficult for an already-started process to continue.

Answer (score 1):

From the definitions it is clear that a *deterrent* affects the desire or intention of someone to take a given course of action while a *hindrance* makes it more difficult for someone to actually follow a course of action already chosen.

In the case of the smartphones the higher price *deters* customers from *choosing* to seek out an iPhone so is appropriate in the given context. An example of a *hindrance* to the sale would be a restricted network of dealerships selling the product making it physically difficult to obtain one.

The deterrent or hindrance would only affect one purchase decision at a time but the cumulative effect over many decisions would be to restrict sales of the affected product.

Answer (score -1):

They have overlapping meanings, but are not equal.

A clear definition of deterrent is: ["a thing that discourages or is intended to discourage someone from doing something"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define:deterrent)

So *deterrent* is a good word in the sample sentence, since it means "the high cost of Apple's devices makes it less likely for people to buy iPhones"

*Hindrance* says "this causes a delay or resistance", but it does not address whether that resistance has the actual result of discouraging activity.

All deterrents hinder, but not all hindrances deter.